# For each of the following numbers $n$, decide whether or not $O(G)$ must contain $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose it has elements $a, b \in  G$ with $o(a) = 10$ and $o(b) = 15$. Let $O(G) = \{m : o(g) = m \text{ for some } g \in G\}$ be the set of all numbers that are orders of elements of G. 
>   (a) Find a subgroup of $G$ having order 3, and show that $3 \in O(G)$. 
>   (b) For each of the following numbers $n$, decide whether or not $O(G)$ must contain $n:
> n=7, n=5, \text{ and } n=25.$

**My attempt:**
a) We have $G = \{e, a, a^2,..., a^9, b, b^2,..., b^{14},ab, a^2b,..., ab^2,ab^3,... \}$ and $|G|=1+9+14+9*14=150$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of order 3. By Lagrange theorem $|H|$ divides $|G|$, so if we want to find the subgroup of order 3, we need an element of $G$ of order $3$, hence $H = \{e,b^5,b^{10}\}.$ Since $b^5 \in G$ has order $3, 3 \in O(G)$. 
b) To see if $n \in O(G)$, we need to find out if there is any element of G of order n. If there is $n$ must divide |G|. Then since $7\nmid 150$, $5\mid 150$, $25\mid 150$, $n$ can be 5 or 25.

Is this a valid proof? Any corrections would be appreciated.

Comment: @EricTowers, I've just edited my solution, can you take another look at it? Thanks

Comment: "it has elements" means the following specification tells me about some of the elements of $G$, it does not exclude additional elements that are not described.  If we were describing exactly the elements of $G$, I would expect "it is generated by", "it is exactly", or something else that indicates the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ is the entirety of $G$.  This cold be a translation issue, so it would be good to determine whether $G$ can contain elements no in the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Also, how do you know whether $aba$ is in the list of elements you wrote down for $G$?

Comment: I think I missed that, and how do you list all elements of $G$? I keep missing some elements...

Comment: Knowing that $G$ has elements of orders 10 and 15 is not enough to tell you what $G$ is or even how many elements it has – there are many finite groups with elements of those orders. Some of them have elements of order 7, some don't; some of them have elements of order 25, and some don't.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, so if G is generated by $a$ and $b$, then how many elements does $G$ have? Did I miss any element?

Comment: First of all, it says nowhere that $G$ is generated by $a$ and $b$. But even if $G$ is generated by $a$ and $b$, it could have $30$ elements, or $60$, or $90$, or pretty much any multiple of $30$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, can you explain pls why it's multiple of $30$ in that case?

Comment: Order of an element divides order of the group. So order of group is divisible by both $10$ and $15$, hence, by $30$.

Comment: Are we OK now, dxdydz?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes, thanks for the explanation

Comment: Maybe you'd like to write up and post an answer, then, dxdydz.